# Failure trying to deploy GWT on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, gwt

I am working on a GWT application. The app. is working in dev mode.

I am working on a gwt project and trying to deploy it to Apache Tomcat. I have never used Apache Tomcat before and I am rather new to Java and GWT. My tomcat server seems to be up and running as I see the "If you see this you have succesfully installed Tomcat" on localhost:8080/

After I got Tomcat up and running I used Eclipse GWT Compile to compile my app. I have copied my .html file and .css file + the war folder to C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\webapps\MyAPP\

Opening the .html file (file:///C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps/PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrder.html) gives me my ui (login screen), but when making the first RPC call (loggin in) I am getting the error "FailureUnable to initiate the asynchronous service invocation (PurchaseOrderService_Proxy.checkUsernameAndPassword) -- check the network connection"

My thougts are that something is incorrect in my web.xml or my service class

```
PurchaseOrderService.java

package com.google.gwt.sample.purchaseorder.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.google.gwt.sample.purchaseorder.client.model.Brands;
import com.google.gwt.sample.purchaseorder.client.model.Item;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("exampleservice")
public interface PurchaseOrderService extends RemoteService {

  boolean checkUsernameAndPassword(String value, String value2);
  ArrayList<Item> getPersonalInfo();
  HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> getListOfPurchaseOrderSortedFromBrands();
  String createExcelExportFile(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> exportMap);
}
```

web.xml:

```
  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>purchaseOrderServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.sample.purchaseorder.server.PurchaseOrderServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>purchaseOrderServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/purchaseorder/exampleservice</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>PurchaseOrder.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Opening the .html file
>   (file:///C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps/PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrder.html)
>   gives me my ui (login screen), but when making the first RPC call
>   (loggin in) I am getting the error "FailureUnable to initiate the
>   asynchronous service invocation
>   (PurchaseOrderService_Proxy.checkUsernameAndPassword) -- check the
>   network connection"

This is not how you access the application running in Tomcat. Your tomcat is running @ localhost:8080 so you have to access using `http://localhost:8080/<app_context_root>/filename.html`

Comment: if I try to access http://localhost:8080/webapps/war/PurchaseOrder.html I get a 404! Is there more to it than copying the war folder to the webapps folder in the apache-tomcat-8.0.15 folder after having started the tomcat folder?

Comment: I got it working. But now I am getting a 500 server error after logging in. I will create a new question for this.